# phoengap 4 not building - android-studio\sdk\platform-tools\tools\lib\build.template

Tags: android, cordova

I have just updated from `phonegap v3.5.0` to `phonegap v4.0.0` and since then I have created a new project:

```
phonegap create jamie
cd jamie
phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova platform add android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova platform add android'
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
cp: no such file or directory: C:\var\www\mywarhammer.co.uk\public\app\jamie\icon.png


Running command: C:\var\www\mywarhammer.co.uk\public\app\jamie\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\phonedev\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools\tools\lib\build.template' 
etc.....

Error: C:\var\www\mywarhammer.co.uk\public\app\jamie\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
etc.....
```

What I find weird/worring is that I have ran all the updates and installs with Android SDK Manager and know that `build.template` is located at: `C:\phonedev\android-studio\sdk\tools\lib\build.template`

So why is it looking in the wrong location and how can I fix this?

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am facing same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the update from v3 to v4 they have moved where the `build.template` file is located.

```
//New location
android-studio/sdk/tools/lib/build.template

//Old Location
android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/tools/lib/build.template
```

**The fix**

```
//Broken code inside your path
ANDROID_HOME: C:\phonedev\android-studio\sdk\platform-tool

//Working path - Make sure ANDROID_HOME is pointing to the correct folder
ANDROID_HOME=C:\phonedev\android-studio\sdk //in my case
```

Sited from:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/507

Answer (score 0):

in my case the ant produced by node.js was the reason.
I replaced it with one from appache and was put directly on c
it worked fine
good luck to everyone

Comment: Ignorance here, but dare to give some more details on this :)?